# Garbage collection when work is done with single or multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, garbage-collection

I have a JDBC program which inserts around 50000 rows in a table. I have 2 version of this program. First one insert 50000 rows using one thread while 2nd version inserts 50000 rows using 5 threads (each thread inserting 10000 rows).

Now when I do profiling for both the program I found that Garbage Collection is taking more CPU cycles when 5 threads are used (44256 for one thread Vs 401836 for 5 thread). Profiler also give me that number of objects created by each program are almost the same.

I am wondering what is making GC to take more cycle in multi threaded program. The work done by both the program is same (inserting 50000 rows) and even the number of objects are also same.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: I suppose you are not using one JDBC connection concurrently in five threads. So there's already a difference, stuff may be cached internally for one connection. Same for statements, etc.

Comment: Isn't each Thread a root for the garbage collection to check? That means there are five more roots to consider when detecting garbage.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But the hypothesis would be that each thread creates  only a fifth of the number of objects created by a single thread. So the graph walked starting from each root should be smaller.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, but there are more graphs to walk which has its own overhead + I assume more objects are created and discarded per second meaning more work per time unit, etc, maybe the new generation overflows sooner leading to more old generation collections instead of evictions from the new generation, etc.

Comment: It could always just be bad luck.  Perhaps 44,256 is the # of cycles required for a small GC and 5 threads just happened to push into the bounds needed for a large GC.  Can you determine how many of each type of CCs are occurring?  Also, some profilers can track the memory allocated by a thread.  How does that compare between the two?

Comment: Can you show us the code that inserts the records? Maybe that gives us a clue.

Comment: I think the short answer is that garbage collection performance is difficult to predict and involves a lot of different factors. Ideally GC shouldn't be a large part of the workload, so the ~10% variation in GC overhead that you're seeing doesn't seem like that big a deal to me.

Comment: Without any details on what GC you were using, how many cores your machine had, how the heap was configured and what kind of profiler you used, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every insert probably creates objects in the JVM, which must later be garbage collected.

If you perform inserts in parallel in multiple threads, then it's likely that you will get higher "throughput" (inserts per second) than you would if you performed inserts sequentially.

*Background: This is because every individual insert, will require a round trip to the database, but if you do inserts in parallel, then another thread can start an insert before the round trips have finished in the others.*

The multithreaded case probably creates more garbage objects in the same amount of time than the single threaded case.

Many garbage collectors are [generational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29). This means that they use concurrent algorithms which do not pause the VM to reclaim the memory from the pool of memory containing the most recently allocated (and discarded) objects - aka "eden space". Eden space is often fixed in size. If this pool fills up faster than the concurrent algorithm can reclaim space, then it can trigger a full garbage collection (full GC), which pauses the whole VM.

So long story short, you might be seeing higher GC overhead in the multithreaded case, because multithreading is giving you higher throughput in your program.

*As a side note: if you want to make your program faster, take a look at the [JDBC batch APIs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm). These allow you to bulk-insert many rows in a single round trip to the database.*